Update the existing records in DE, which is appended by another SQL with existing automation
I have an automation in which one SQL is appending the dada in Target DE, latter I found that this SQL is not getting values for all fields.
So now I am updating my existing SQL to get values for missing fields that will append the future data correctly in future. But now I also want to update the vaules for the fields which are missing and already existing in Target DE.
AS the existing SQL have append data action.
How I can update the affected records which are already present in Target DE?

To achieve the updates you are looking for, you can use the 'Update' action in your SQL query activity. This will allow your SQL query to update the fields in records that already exist in the target DE based on the matching primary key.
Process:

Change the SQL Query Action: In your automation, change the action of your SQL Query Activity from 'Append' to 'Update'. This is crucial because 'Append' will only add new records to the end of your DE and will not modify existing records.
Ensure You Have a Primary Key: For the 'Update' action to work, your target DE must have a primary key or a set of fields that uniquely identify each record. The SQL query will use this key to determine which records to update.
Write an Update-Suitable SQL Query: Your SQL query should select not only new data but also existing data that needs updating (you appear to have done this already).


Thanks for your input

If this answer gave you what you needed, would be grateful if you could mark the answer as correct.
